# HTML set label width in css?

Tags: html, css

How does one set a label width for all labels?

CSS:

```
label {
    width: 180px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for = "customerName">Name:</label><input type = "text" name = "customerName" required><br>
```

but the label is "Name:" length. I expected that the label will be 180px wide. It's the same width whether the css code exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **display: inline-block;**

***Explanation:***

The label is an inline element, meaning it is only as big as it needs to be.

Set the display property to either inline-block or block in order for the width property to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

**Labels are by default inline elements. Inline elements don't take width or height.**
Make them inline-block and then try.
Use *display:inline-block*